# How do I make qtreewidget header transparent?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want the treewidget header to look as if it's a label, so, I guess, I have to make it transparent? How do I do it?

I tried `treeWidget->setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget::header {background-color: transparent}");` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is not a subcontrol of an itemview, thus `QTreeWidget::header` will not work. The header rather is a children widget of the view. 
That means you could access the header via stylesheets with `QTreeWidget QHeaderView {/*style here*/ }`

For the background color of a header view you can check out the  [official Qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview).

In your case as you are setting the stylesheet directly to the view you can omit the parent so the following will do what you asked for:

```
treeWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color: transparent; }");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the headers transparent, you have to add the following to the widget stylesheet:

```css
QAbstractItemView QHeaderView {
    show-decoration-selected: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
QAbstractItemView::section QHeaderView::section {
    show-decoration-selected: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```